# How to fill a char array without loop

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I need help with filling up a char array in c++ with a letter and without using a loop. This is what i have so far.

```
int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    char canvas[n][m] = {{'B'}};
```

This however won't work. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Hint: `std::vector`.

Comment: @scohe001 Wouldn't loop take a long time?

Comment: You are trying to create a VLA, which is not included in the C++ standard (but is available as an extension in some implementations)

Comment: Hint 2: VLAs like `char canvas[n][m]` are [not part of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) and have a tendency of blowing up the stack. `std::vector` will solve both of your problems.

Comment: ok i will try vector. thx!!!

Comment: @Shadow_Walker If you're writing values to many different locations, somebody has to do the loop. All you can hope for is that somebody writes the loop better than you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with a 2D `std::vector`:

```
int n, m;
std::cin >> n >> m;
std::vector<std::vector<char>> canvas(n, std::vector<char>(m, 'B'));
```

Comment: Entry #9,582,108 in our ongoing series of "Why you should be using `std::vector`"

Comment: A 1D flat vector would be even better than a 2D sparse vector: `std::vector<char> canvas(n*m, 'B');` Though, the code is dealing with `char`, so there is always `std::string` instead: `std::string canvas(n*m, 'B');`